# PHP Merging Two Images results in black bounding box around merged image

Tags: php, gd

I use a barcode class to generate a barcode and then merge the produced barcode with another image.

The problem is that when the images are merged, the barcode is surrounded in a black bounding box.

At first I thought this was because I was merging a gif (barcode) with a jpeg and setting the header as jpg but when I merged with a gif and updated the header to match the problematic black box still remains.

New gif version of code:

```
$bc = new PrintBarcode('DARP CODE');
$bc->drawVoucher();
$src = $bc->getVoucher();

header('Content-Type: image/gif');


$bg  = imagecreatefromgif('images/voucher.gif'); 

imagealphablending($src,true);
imagesavealpha($src, true);

imagecopymerge($bg, $src, 40, 380, 0, 0, imagesx($bg), imagesy($bg), 100);

imagegif($bg, null, 100);


imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($bg);
```

These are the docs from the barcode class that state the output is a gif: http://www.shayanderson.com/php/php-barcode-generator-class-code-39.htm

[image]

you can see it in the image above where the image ends and the barcode begins when the base image should be visible without the black bounding box of the barcode.

After a little bit of investigating I can confirm that the black box is definitely coming from the barcode image. I tried to replace the black pixels with white but as expected it made the barcode invisible....

Comment: How big is the final image that you've generated?

Comment: @Jack the base image is 798 x 526 but when the barcode is overlayed it goes beyond the bottom border of the base image but about a pixel as you can see above. The chrome inspector tools don't give me the dimensions of the image for some reason, must be something to do with how it's dynamically generated.

Comment: Well, you set the y-coordinate to 380px from the top, so that might actually go beyond the bottom of the background image ...

Comment: @Jack yeah, the co-ordinates move the actual barcode around the base image, but any overspill is a black bounding box, I can hide the black box if I position the barcode exactly in the bottom right corner but that's not where I want the barcode to be and it's just hiding the problem rather than directly fixing it.